# Esri file geodatabase data migrated to PostGIS through FME becomes non-editable in QGIS

Tags: qgis, editing, file-geodatabase, fme-form

I loaded a layer (point) from Esri file geodatabase to PostGIS (PostgreSQL) using FME and when I load it in QGIS, I cannot edit the layer.

Am I missing any step in FME data migration process?

I used the 'drop&create' table handling option in FME.

Comment: Try to create a constraint on the indexer of your table(layer)...

Answer (score 1):

QGIS needs a Primary Key to translate the edits back to the table. One way to do this is to add it as an attribute in the (Feature)Writer:

[image]